# C++. 1Class with changing parameters

Tags: c++, class, parameters

I've got a class with 3 private variables and one public method, that has 2 char parameter variables.

```
class InitLine
{
private:
    char *a;
    char b, c;

public:
    InitLine(char *inita, char initc);
    Init(char *a, char c);
};
```

Now the definition of the method is simple:

```
Initline::Init(char *a, char c)
{
    for (b=0; b<c; b++)
        *(a+c)=0;
}
```

Now my question is: If I wish to repeat the same actions with different parametertypes (*a and c, or one of them becomes an integer e.g.), is it necessary to create a new class, or can I use the existing one, doing some 'typecasting' or some other trick I don't know yet?

Thanks and regards

Uwe

Comment: same action with different parameter smells like overloads and templates..you can do it..

Comment: Prior to answering: your naming convention is terrible. What is `a`, `b`, `c`? Next, you use a class field b in the place, where a local variable should have been used. These details make reading your code really tough. I formatted your code to be more readable.

Comment: not sure what exactly this code will do *(a+c)=0;...does this code has some meaning or just random

Comment: Dear all, the code is just an' example code and you should'nt  analize, what the code does, but just tell me, how it is possible to use the same class with changing parameter types.

Comment: The code just initializes an array. It's written with 'pointers' instead of an 'array' and it works but its not complete. 'b' is no 'classfield', but just a local counter and I thought that 3 variables could also be named a,b and c without creating too much confusion.

Comment: no, `b` refers to the class data member `InitLine::b`. If you're getting that confused by code _you_ wrote, imagine how odd it looks to everyone else.

Comment: Ok, I ment a private variable and it seems quite obvious. Are You satisfied now? Anyway, the other members, except one, had no problem to analize the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use templates, make the Init function a template of your arguments type.

```
template <typename T>
Init(char*a , T c){}
```

for instance

Answer (score 1):

You have many places in your code, which should be fixed prior to any further operations.

1. Naming convention is terrible. What is `a`, `b`, `c`?
2. You use `b` as a loop indexer, while a local variable should be used there instead.
3. You don't show us, what *is* `a`. Where is it allocated? What is the size of memory pointed to by `a`?

I guess, that your code should look like the following:

```
class InitLine
{
private:
    char * data;
    int count;

public:
    InitLine(char * newData, int newCount)
    {
        // Possible error checking?
        data = newData;
        count = newCount;
    }

    // No parameters needed here, I guess
    void Init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            data[i] = 0;
    }
};
```

As for your question, I'm not really sure, what you are trying to achieve and what do you want to know. If you want to write a generic class holding any type of arrays, you have to use templates:

```
template <typename T>
class InitLine
{
private:
    T * data;
    int count;

public:
    InitLine(T * newData, int newCount)
    {
        // Possible error checking?
        data = newData;
        count = newCount;
    }

    // No parameters needed here, I guess
    void Init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            data[i] = 0;
    }
};
```

You have to use this class in the following way:

```
InitLine<char> line(myData, myDataSize);
// where myData is a char * and myDataSize is an int
```

If you want to write a few methods differing by their parameters, this technique is called method overloading and is available in C++:

```
void Init(char * a, int b) { /* sth */ }
void Init(int * a, int b) { /* sth */ }
```

Note, that compiler must be able to clearly distinguish, which method should be called. Eg.

```
void Test(int a) { }
void Test(char a) { }

Test(0); // Ambiguity: which method should be called?
```

These are only things coming to my mind, while reading your question. If it is not what you are asking for, consider editing the question to be more specific.

Comment: So I have to repeat the whole decleration and defition of the method? Try to understand the question as the others do instead of concentrating on unimportant details I didn't ask for. Thanks and regards Uwe

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the whole class with different types (not just the Init), e.g. also have int *a; int b,c; then [template classes](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html) are the other trick you don't know yet.

```
template <typename ANYTYPE> class InitLine
{
private:
    ANYTYPE *a;
    ANYTYPE b, c;

public:
    void InitLine(ANYTYPE *inita, ANYTYPE initc);
    void Init(ANYTYPE *a, ANYTYPE c);
};


template <typename ANYTYPE> void Initline<ANYTYPE>::Init(ANYTYPE *a, ANYTYPE c)
{
    for (int b=0; b<c; b++)
        *(a+c)=0;
}


... main()
{
     Initline<int> iline;  // initline class based on type int (ANYTYPE -> int)
     int line[20];

     Initline<char> cline;  // initline class based on type char (ANYTYPE -> char)
     char somechars[30];

     iline.Init(line, 20);
     cline.Init(somechars, 30);
```

Comment: Added more code to main() to show how to make one of type char and one of type int, both based on the template.

Comment: Hello Nicholaz, I think You ment 'char somechars[30]. Today I tried out the method. It didn't work this way, but my compiler just accepts it if you write: template <typename ANYTYPE> ANYTYPE Initline <ANYTYPE>::Init(ANYTYPE *a, ANYTYPE c). Tanks and regards

Comment: Will edit both. Yw ... (checking as correct would be appreciated if this was the answer that helped you solve the problem).